# Lebesgue generalizations of Hilbert spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Is an L[p] space a generalization of Hilbert spaces using Lebesgue integration?

And if this is the case, is it true that Holder's and Minkowski's Inequalities are generalizations of the Cauchy-Schwarz and triangle inequalities using Lebesgue measures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. To start, $L^p$ is a true Banach space, not a "generalized" Banach space.

I assume you use the term Lebesgue integration as contrasted with Riemann integration. You could, if you wanted, define the normed space of all functions $f:[0,1]\to\mathbf{R}$ with $|f|^p$ Riemann-integrable, with norm $\|f\|_p = \int |f|^p$. You might then hope to prove that this is a Banach space, but you would fail (the completion of this space is precisely $L^p([0,1])$).

If you did carry out this programme, you would still want to prove Minkowski's inequality and Holder's inequality, which are generalisations of the triangle and Cauchy-Schwarz inequalities to $p\neq 2$, even though you've decided that you hate Lebesgue.

Edit: In response to your new phrasing, I think it's best to say that Banach spaces are generalized Hilbert spaces. Note that $L^2([0,1])$ is a Hilbert space, but definitely requires Lebesgue integration to ensure that the space is complete. (In general, the correct way to view Lebesgue integration is as the "completion" of Riemann integration.)

Answer (score 1):

$L^p$ space is a generalization of $L^2$ space, and if $p\neq2$ they are not Hilbert. Hilbert space is an abstract concept, and it is more general than $L^2$ spaces. $L^2$ is just one concrete example of a Hilbert space.